# C#, UWP Storyboard - Dynamically add DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames

Tags: c#, uwp

I have some elements that are being added to a UWP view dynamically.  This information is coming from an API.  In theory I could have any number of elements to add.

Part of the element description is an entrance animation - for example, `fade in` - changes opacity from `0` to `element opacity value`

Ordinarily when I do this in the code behind I would write something like:

```cs
Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
KeyTime keyTime1 = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0));
KeyTime keyTime2 = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 500));

DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames daRoot = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
daRoot.KeyFrames.Add(keyTime1.GetKeyFrame(0));
daRoot.KeyFrames.Add(keyTime2.GetKeyFrame(1));
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(daRoot, "Opacity");
Storyboard.SetTarget(daRoot, this.Root);

sb.Children.Add(daRoot);
sb.Begin();
```

`GetKeyFrame()` is an extension method that returns an `EasingDoubleKeyFrame`

My thoughts are that to do this for a number of elements I should just be able to put it in a loop, like so:

```cs
Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
KeyTime keyTime1 = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0));
KeyTime keyTime2 = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 500));

foreach(var el in elements)
{
    DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames da = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
    da.KeyFrames.Add(keyTime1.GetKeyFrame(0));
    da.KeyFrames.Add(keyTime2.GetKeyFrame(1));
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, "Opacity");
    Storyboard.SetTarget(da, el);

    sb.Children.Add(da);
}
sb.Begin();
```

Although an animation happens, it only takes place on the final element in the collection.

I assume that this is because of these lines:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, "Opacity");
Storyboard.SetTarget(da, el);
```

I guess it is because the `da` and `el` have the same 'variable name' and therefore are the same object on each iteration of the loop.

Is there a good way to do the above so that it does the same animation on each element, no matter whether I have 10 or 100 elements?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure on your exact requirements, but this snippet will loop through each element and add the animation to each one individually, it will also wait until the current animation is complete before looping onto the next one.

Please test and let me know if it suits your requirements.

```
private async void btn1_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var el in elements)
    {            
        AnimateOpacity(el.Opacity - 1);
        await Task.Delay(250); 
       //Wait for StoryBoard to complete before moving on to next element
    }
}


//TODO Add this to a class
public void AnimateOpacity(double to, double miliseconds = 250)
{
    var storyboard = new Storyboard();
    var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    doubleAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(miliseconds);
    doubleAnimation.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
    doubleAnimation.To = to;
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, "Opacity");
    Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, el);
    storyboard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

Comment: interesting, i'll check that out.  I had tried a daList, but didn't think to also try a list of the elements - will give that a go and see what happens

Comment: Did this help in the end?

Comment: Hey, sorry it took so long for me to test this out, but no, it still does exactly the same problem.  Have also tried including the `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty` line to use the list item

Comment: Hey, I've edited my answer with another solution based on something I have used in a project of my own, but not 100% sure if it meets your requirements. Still, it may be useful. Let me know.